# How would I make a program go back to the start.

Tags: command-line, bash

So I have my program and I cannot figure out how to make the program loop back to the start. I have more of a program however this is the part where I would like the program to restart if I picked yes exit 0 and exit 1 are placeholders at the moment since I do not know how to make it loop. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
echo "Is that all sir? (Yes/No)"

if [ $word = "Yes" ] 
then exit 0

if [ $word = "No" ]
then exit 1

fi
```

Comment: Who will  type yes or no?

Comment: @AvinashRaj This is a program to simulate a butler. it runs on terminal so the person running the program would type yes/no.

Comment: read is used to get input from the user.

Comment: This smells like a homework assignment.

Comment: Actually no, This is for my own free work. Sometimes i can get extra credit for turning in programs but this is for fun. Just so I could learn how to program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
response=no
while [[ "$response" != "yes" ]]
do
    echo "Is that all? (Yes/No)"
    read -r response
done
```

References and advice:

- The [while command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs) and the [read builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) in the GNU Bash Reference Manual.
- in general, [prefer `[[` to `[`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) (although it does not matter much in this specific case, it's a good habit unless you need specifically `[`)
- same goes for [quoting variable expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) (more discussion [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29))

Comment: However this still doesnt help figure out how to loop or restart the program.

Comment: @Sir_Dippingsauce: The while, do, done keywords make a loop. If the whole program is inside the while loop then the whole program restarts with each loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# While running an infinite loop
while [ 1 ]; do
    # keep asking the user for input (Yes/No).
    echo "Is that all sir? (Yes/No): "
    # the read keyword assigns the input to the word variable
    read word
    # If the user types "Yes" 
    if [ $word = "Yes" ]; then
        # break the loop and finish the script.
        break
    fi
done
```